# MiniProfiler to profile my ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, mvc-mini-profiler

How do I get MiniProfiler to profile my ajax requests

For example:

```
<div id="nav">
 <ul>
    <li onclick="javascript:updateContent(1);">foo 1</li>
    <li onclick="javascript:updateContent(2);">foo 2</li>
    <li onclick="javascript:updateContent(3);">foo 3</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateContent(productId) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetProduct", "Product")',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            traditional: true,
            data: {
                productId: productId
            }
        })
            .success(function (result) {
                // Display the section contents.
                $('#content').html(result);
            })
            .error(function (xhr, status) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            });
        }
</script>
```

I would like to see the performance of each updateContent.

Any ideas?

I am using Asp.net MVC 3 and MiniProfiler 1.9 installed via NuGet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Already built in, you don't need to do anything special.

Each time you execute an ajax request a new timing will show up.

You can see a demo on http://data.stackexchange.com .. write a query and run it, you will see the timing add to the list.